# Наследование html-шаблонов произошло неверным образом (Django)

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я составил базовую структуру html-страницы ('ecommerce/templates/ecommerce/base.html'), проставил теги в тех местах, где будет появляться различная от контекста информация. Но при написании кода для дочернего html-файла ('ecommerce/templates/ecommerce/index.html'), в котором я проставил теги также, на выводе я вижу только надписи тегов и отдельные элементы, которые передают заголовок и параграф со стилем текста для страницы.

В чем может быть проблема? Почему я вижу теги, и не вижу готового шаблона для страницы?

```
Код base.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
      <a href="http://localhost:63342/personalsite/personalsite/ecommerce/templates/ecommerce/index.html" class="d-flex align-items-center link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="32" class="me-2" viewBox="0 0 118 94" role="img"><title>Эмблема</title><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24.509 0c-6.733 0-11.715 5.893-11.492 12.284.214 6.14-.064 14.092-2.066 20.577C8.943 39.365 5.547 43.485 0 44.014v5.972c5.547.529 8.943 4.649 10.951 11.153 2.002 6.485 2.28 14.437 2.066 20.577C12.794 88.106 17.776 94 24.51 94H93.5c6.733 0 11.714-5.893 11.491-12.284-.214-6.14.064-14.092 2.066-20.577 2.009-6.504 5.396-10.624 10.943-11.153v-5.972c-5.547-.529-8.934-4.649-10.943-11.153-2.002-6.484-2.28-14.437-2.066-20.577C105.214 5.894 100.233 0 93.5 0H24.508zM80 57.863C80 66.663 73.436 72 62.543 72H44a2 2 0 01-2-2V24a2 2 0 012-2h18.437c9.083 0 15.044 4.92 15.044 12.474 0 5.302-4.01 10.049-9.119 10.88v.277C75.317 46.394 80 51.21 80 57.863zM60.521 28.34H49.948v14.934h8.905c6.884 0 10.68-2.772 10.68-7.727 0-4.643-3.264-7.207-9.012-7.207zM49.948 49.2v16.458H60.91c7.167 0 10.964-2.876 10.964-8.281 0-5.406-3.903-8.178-11.425-8.178H49.948z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
        <span class="fs-4">Интернет-магазин</span>
      </a>
      <nav class="d-inline-flex mt-2 mt-md-0 ms-md-auto">
        <a class="me-3 py-2 link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none" href="http://localhost:63342/personalsite/personalsite/ecommerce/templates/ecommerce/about.html">О сайте</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

Код index.html

{% extends 'ecommerce/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Главная страница
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Это главная страница</h1>
    <p>Здесь указан параграф страницы</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Отдельно хочу указать, что я только осваиваю Django. Версия фреймворка - 5.0.2. Я хочу также узнать отдельную информацию насчет особенностей работы с этим фреймворком. В настройках settings.py в разделе templates я не добавлял ничего в раздел DIRS. Глупый вопрос: мне нужно это исправлять? К тому же Django предусматривает наличие движка для создания шаблонов под названием DjangoTemplates. Его достаточно, чтобы создавать шаблоны?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.
Вся проблема заключалась в том, что путь к моему проекту содержал название адреса с кириллицей. Составил проект на другой адрес, и теперь все работает как нужно